# How to add another time counter to my functioning sketch?

Tags: timers

I have a functional sketch that I run on an Arduino Uno, the output controlling a fan module; I need another timer to run a 2nd fan and I would like to use another output on the Uno to do that rather than using another unit.

What my sketch does is as follows:

- counts 15 minutes (interval_1)
- starts the fan for 1 minute (interval_2)
- starts another cycle.

What I need to do is to add another function that will start fan#2 for 15 sec (interval_3) when the cycle starts, using another output (relayPin_1), then stop.

So the flow will be:

- counts 15 minutes (interval_1)
- starts fan#1 for 60 sec (interval_2)
- starts fan#2 for 15 sec (interval_3)
- resets and starts another cycle.

Unfortunately, can't figure out how to insert the 2nd timer.

Sketch is below, if you have any ideas that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
const byte relayPin = 4;                           // fan#1 control on pin 4, 
const byte relayPin_1 = 7;                         // humidifier fan#2 control on pin 7,
const unsigned long interval_1 = 1000UL * 60,      // RUN timer, msec
                    interval_2 = 1000UL * 60 * 15, // OFF timer, msec
                    interval_3 = 1000UL * 15;      // Humidifier timer
unsigned long currentMillis, previousMillis = 0;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);   // Output#1
    pinMode(relayPin_1, OUTPUT); //Output#2
    // relayPin_1 controls the humidifier's fan#2
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // at startup, fan is ON for interval_1 duration
    currentMillis = millis() - previousMillis;
    if (currentMillis <= interval_1) {
        digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);    // fan ON
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // LED ON (blinking)
        delay(333 / 2);
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // LED Off
        delay(999);
    }

    // when interval_1 is reached, turn fan OFF for the duration of interval_2
    else if (currentMillis <= (interval_1 + interval_2)) {
        digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);    // fan OFF
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); // led OFF
    }
    else {
        // reset the timer
        previousMillis = millis();
    }

}
```

---

Okay... I had time to play with it today; what it does:
it starts both fan#1 and fan#2, then stops fan#2 at (interval_1 + interval_2), but fan#1 continues running until the cycle ends.
Therefore: fan#1 runs for 35 sec, fan#2 runs for 15 sec, as it should; and the cycle is stopped for 30 sec as it should.
However, I can't make fan#1 to run for only 20 sec. as it is defined.

```
const byte relayPin = 4;   // recyrculation fan#1 control on pin 4, 
const byte relayPin_1 = 7; // humidifier fan#2 control on pin 7,
const unsigned long interval_1 = 1000UL * 20,    // RUN timer fan#1, msec
                    interval_2 = 1000UL * 15,    // RUN timer fan#2, msec
                    interval_3 = 1000UL * 30;    // OFF timer
unsigned long currentMillis, previousMillis = 0;

void setup() {
   // put your setup code here, to run once:
   pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT); // Output#1
    pinMode(relayPin_1, OUTPUT); //Output#2
     pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); }

void loop() {
// at startup, fan#1 & fan#2 are ON 
 currentMillis = millis() - previousMillis;
  if (currentMillis < interval_1) {
    digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);   // fan#1 ON
    digitalWrite(relayPin_1, HIGH); // fan#2 ON
     digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // builtin LED ON

 } else if (currentMillis < (interval_1 + interval_2)) {
    digitalWrite(relayPin_1, LOW); // fan#2 OFF

   // when (interval_1 + interval_2) is reached, turn fans OFF for the duration of interval_3
 } else if (currentMillis < (interval_1 + interval_2 + interval_3)) {
   digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);      // fan#1 OFF
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); // led OFF

 } else {
   // reset the timer  
     previousMillis = millis(); }
 }
```

Comment: your description of the fan cycles is unclear .... do both fans start at the same time?

Comment: draw a timing chart on paper ... it nay help you to visualize the required code

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description. In your description you want the fan off for 15 minutes, then on for 1 minute. You have your fan on for the entire 15 minute interval_1, then off for 1 minute.

Comment: The code comments on your intervals suggest that interval_1 is your run (fan 1 on) time and interval_2 is your fan off time. That is what your code does, but not what you say in your description. Which is correct?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want it to do. Please add a clear statement of your goal. For the first interval (20 seconds?) which fans should be on? Then for the 2nd, 15 second interval which fans should be on? And I gather that you want both fans off for interval 3 (30 seconds)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get your logic straightened out, you should be able to add as many cases to your if statement as you want:

```
  if (currentMillis <= interval_1) {
      // Before end of interval 1, fan off.
  } else if (currentMillis <= (interval_1 + interval_2)) {
      // In interval 2, fan on
  } else if (currentMillis <= (interval_1 + interval_2 + interval_3 )) {
      // In interval 3, fan2 on
  } else {
      // Turn everything off
      // reset the timer  
  }
```

Comment: In any case, I showed in my answer how to adjust your code to have 3 different intervals, then turn everything off after the end of the last interval. You can extend that pattern to as many intervals as you want,

Comment: If you can't get it to work edit your question and put the new code at the end, along with what it is doing wrong.